# Is it possile to search for text in comments?

Tags: feature-request, support

I read a comment that was interesting to me and lost track of where it occurred. I cannot seem to search for key words I know were part of the comment to locate it. All that appears are the usual Q and A posts. Is it possible to also search for text in comments in some way?

If it is not currently possible I am requesting this as a new feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments are considered "ephemeral" and "second-class citizens" on the site. If a comment is informative, it should ideally be expanded into a full-fledged answer, or its information edited into the post it is attached to. It is thus “by design” that comments cannot be searched for. To perform such searches, you may use Google rather than Stack Exchange's search engine.